# How to reverse integer in Prolog using tail-recursion?

Tags: recursion, prolog, integer, reverse, tail-recursion

I would like to make a predicat reverse(N,Result) in Prolog.

For example:

- reverse(12345,Result).
- Result = 54321.

I have to use tail-recursion. I can use *, +, - and divmod/4 and that's all.I can't use list.

I can reverse a number < 100 but I don't find how to finish my code, I can't complete my code to reverse integers bigger than 100 correctly.

```
reverse(N,N):-
    N <10,
    N>0.

reverse(N,Result):-
    N > 9,
    iter(N,0,Result).

iter(N,Ac,Result):-
    N  < 100, !,
    divmod(N,10,Q,R),
    R1 is R*10,
    Result is Q + R1.
```

Can I have some help please ?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: I tried to say hello but I can't edit my post

Comment: @Yashrod Did you try to split a number into digits' list, then to reverse the list, and then to build the number reversed?

Comment: @AntonDanilov sorry I should have said that I can't use list, I edit my post.

Comment: Why wouldn't `reverse(N, N)` be true if `N >= 0` rather than just `N > 0`?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the use of [CLP(FD)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html), since it offers declarative reasoning over integer arithmetic and a lot of Prolog systems provide it. Concerning the digit-reversal, I recommend you take a look at entry [A004086 in *The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences*](https://oeis.org/A004086). In the paragraph headed *FORMULA*, you'll find, among others, the following formulae:

```
a(n) = d(n,0) with d(n,r) = if n=0 then r else d(floor(n/10),r*10+(n mod 10))
```

These can be translated into a predicates by adding an additional argument for the reversed number. First let's give it a nice declarative name, say `digits_reversed/2`. Then the relation can be expressed using `#>/2`, `#=/2`, `(/)/2`, `+/2`, `mod/2` and tail-recursion:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

digits_reversed(N,X) :-
   digits_reversed_(N,X,0).

digits_reversed_(0,R,R).
digits_reversed_(N,X,R) :-
   N #> 0,
   N0 #= N/10,
   R1 #= R*10 + (N mod 10),
   digits_reversed_(N0,X,R1).
```

Note that `digits_reversed/2` correspond to `a(n)` and `digits_reversed_/3` corresponds to `d(n,r)` in the above formulae. Now let's query the predicate with the example from your post:

```
?- digits_reversed(12345,R).
R = 54321 ;
false.
```

The predicate can also be used in the other direction, that is ask *What number has been reversed to obtain 54321?* However, since leading zeros of numbers are omitted one reversed number has infinitely many original numbers:

```
?- digits_reversed(N,54321).
N = 12345 ;
N = 123450 ;
N = 1234500 ;
N = 12345000 ;
N = 123450000 ;
N = 1234500000 ;
N = 12345000000 ;
N = 123450000000 ;
.
.
.
```

Even the most general query yields solutions but you'll get residual goals as an answer for numbers with more than one digit:

```
?- digits_reversed(N,R).
N = R, R = 0 ;              % <- zero
N = R,
R in 1..9 ;                 % <- other one-digit numbers
N in 10..99,                % <- numbers with two digits
N mod 10#=_G3123,
N/10#=_G3135,
_G3123 in 0..9,
_G3123*10#=_G3159,
_G3159 in 0..90,
_G3159+_G3135#=R,
_G3135 in 1..9,
R in 1..99 ;
N in 100..999,              % <- numbers with three digits
N mod 10#=_G4782,
N/10#=_G4794,
_G4782 in 0..9,
_G4782*10#=_G4818,
_G4818 in 0..90,
_G4818+_G4845#=_G4842,
_G4845 in 0..9,
_G4794 mod 10#=_G4845,
_G4794 in 10..99,
_G4794/10#=_G4890,
_G4890 in 1..9,
_G4916+_G4890#=R,
_G4916 in 0..990,
_G4842*10#=_G4916,
_G4842 in 0..99,
R in 1..999 ;
.
.
.
```

To get actual numbers with the query above, you have to restrict the range of `N` and label it after the predicate has posted the arithmetic constraints:

```
?- N in 10..20, digits_reversed(N,R), label([N]).
N = 10,
R = 1 ;
N = R, R = 11 ;
N = 12,
R = 21 ;
N = 13,
R = 31 ;
N = 14,
R = 41 ;
N = 15,
R = 51 ;
N = 16,
R = 61 ;
N = 17,
R = 71 ;
N = 18,
R = 81 ;
N = 19,
R = 91 ;
N = 20,
R = 2 ;
false.
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you don't want a constraints based solution, or if you using a Prolog system not supporting constraints, an alternative solution is:

```
reverse_digits(N, M) :-
    (   integer(N) ->
        reverse_digits(N, 0, M)
    ;   integer(M),
        reverse_digits(M, 0, N)
    ).

reverse_digits(0, M, M) :- !.
reverse_digits(N, M0, M) :-
    N > 0,
    R is N div 10,
    M1 is M0 * 10 + N mod 10,
    reverse_digits(R, M1, M).
```

This solution can be used with either argument bound to an integer and leaves no spurious choice-points:

```
?- reverse_digits(12345, M).
M = 54321.

?- reverse_digits(N, 12345).
N = 54321.

?- reverse_digits(12345, 54321).
true.
```

But note that this solution, unlike the constraints based solution, cannot be used as a *generator* of pairs of integers that satisfy the relation:

```
?- reverse_digits(N, M).
false.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
reverseNumber(N,R):-reverse_acc(N,0,R).
reverse_acc(0,Acc,Acc).
reverse_acc(N,Acc,R):- C is N mod 10, N1 is N div 10, 
                                     Acc1 is Acc * 10 + C, 
                                     reverse_acc(N1, Acc1,R).
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?